# Adding labels to a table: columns and rows

Tags: tables

[image]

Can anybody help me? I know how to build the table but I don’t know how to add the “Users” and “Movies” labels.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\text{ \textbf{Movies}}
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |  c |  }


\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
1 & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|} 
2 & 4 &  & 3 & 1 &  &   & 3  &   \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|} 
3 & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
4 & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
5 & 3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
6 & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
\end{tabular}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can have it with `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`, but I'd use Ti*k*Z for that. Anyway: what have you tried so far? Please add a minimal code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my recommended version, which doesn't use any tables at all, but a powerful tool called Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum size=.75cm,anchor=center}] {%
& 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\
4 &  & 3 & 1 &  &   & 3  &   \\
& 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\
&   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\
3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\
& \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\
};
\draw[step=0.75] (m-1-1.north west) grid (m-6-8.south east);
\begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
\foreach \i in {1,...,8} \path (m-1-\i.north) node[above] {\i};
\foreach \i in {1,...,6} \path (m-\i-1.west)  node[left]  {\i};
\end{scope}
\path (m-1-5.north west) node[above=1em] {Movies};
\path (m-3-1.south west) node[left=1em] {Users};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I don't nest tables, but use a `\multirow` to center "Movies" and "Users":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Movies}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} \\ \cline{3-10}
\multirow{6}{*}{Users}&1 & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ \cline{3-10}
&2 & 4 &  & 3 & 1 &  &   & 3  &   \\ \cline{3-10}
&3 & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ \cline{3-10}
&4 & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ \cline{3-10}
&5 & 3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\ \cline{3-10}
&6 & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ \cline{3-10}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can nest tables.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Tables can be nested}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 & Movies\\
 Users&
 \begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |  c |  }


\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
1 & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|} 
2 & 4 &  & 3 & 1 &  &   & 3  &   \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|} 
3 & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
4 & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
5 & 3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
6 & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{10}{c}}
&   & \Block{1-*}{\bfseries \sffamily Movies} \\
&   & 1 & 2                      & 3                      & 4 & 5                      & 6 & 7                      & 8 \\
\Block{*-1}{\bfseries \sffamily Users}
& 1 & \Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}     
        & 5                      &                        & 2 & 4                      &   &                        &   \\ 
& 2 & 4 &                        & 3                      & 1 &                        &   & 3                      &   \\ 
& 3 &   & 5                      & 4                      &   & 5                      &   & 4                      &   \\ 
& 4 &   &                        &                        &   &                        & 1 & 1                      & 2 \\ 
& 5 & 3 &                        & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &   & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 &                        &   \\ 
& 6 &   & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2             &   & 4                      &   & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &   \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]